# How to remock libs in jest test?

Tags: javascript, mocking, jestjs

```
jest.mock('../redux/storeConfigure', () => () => ({
  getState: () => ({ auth: { token: 'TEST_TOKEN' } })
}))

import { prepareRequestHeaders } from './fetch'

describe('prepareRequestHeaders', () => {
  it('returns header with Authorization if token is set', () => {
    expect(prepareRequestHeaders()['Authorization']).toBe('Bearer TEST_TOKEN')
  })

  it('returns header without Authorization if token is not set', () => {
    ?????
  })
})
```

In `prepareRequestHeaders` I import `../redux/storeConfigure`

How to remock `../redux/storeConfigure` with other implementation?

EDIT:

```
/* fetch.js */
import { store } from '../app'

export const prepareRequestHeaders = () => {
  const headers = {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }

  const { token } = store.getState().auth
  if (token) {
    headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`
  }

  return headers
}

/* app.js */

import storeConfigure from './redux/storeConfigure'

export const store = storeConfigure()

/* Directories strucutre */
- redux
  - storeConfigure.js
- api
  - fetch.js
  - api.test.js
app.js
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work out:

```
let mockGetState;

jest.mock('../redux/storeConfigure', () => () => {
  mockGetState = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ auth: { token: 'TEST_TOKEN' } })
  return { getState: mockGetState }
})

import { prepareRequestHeaders } from './fetch'

describe('prepareRequestHeaders', () => {
  it('returns header with Authorization if token is set', () => {
    expect(prepareRequestHeaders()['Authorization']).toBe('Bearer TEST_TOKEN')
  })

  it('returns header without Authorization if token is not set', () => {
    mockGetState.mockReturnValueOnce({auth: {token: 'SOMETHING_ELSE'}})
    // make your assertion
  })
})
```

When you assign to a Jest mock (`jest.fn()`) you can change its return value whenever you want. The name of it has to start with `mock` because of mock hoisting

Comment: do you know maybe why could I have `ReferenceError: mockGetState is not defined at src/api/api.test.js:4:16`?

Comment: Ah, it's hoisting... If you can post some minimal version of `fetch.js` and `../redux/storeConfigure.js` I can paste you a full example that works after running it :)

Comment: I've added code in question edit above. Thanks in advance ;)  @SimenB ^

Comment: `storeConfigure` just gives a redux store?